# How to assess mp4 video quality in code with macOS

Tags: cocoa, video, ffmpeg, codec, avkit

**Q1**) How can I get video file details with macOS APIs?
**Q2**) How do I assess video quality of an mp4 file?

I need a program to separate a large archive of mp4 files based on the video quality - i.e., clarity, sharpness - roughly, where they'd appear along the TV spectrum of analog -> 720 -> 1080 -> 2/4k. In this case, audio, color levels, file size, CPU/GPU load, etc., are not considerations *per se*.

**Q1**) It is easy to find "natural" dimensions with AVPlayer. A bit more poking around (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avpartialasyncproperty/3816116-formatdescriptions ), my files have "avc1" as the media subtype; I gather that means h264. Can't locate ways to get more details with Apple APIs, like bit rate, that even Quicktime Player provides.

Lots of info is available with `ffprobe`, so I added it to my program. You too can *embed a CLI program that runs inside a macOS application* in background - see code at bottom.

**Q2**) To a video noob, dimensions are the obvious first approximation for video quality ... and codec, but mine have previously been converted to h264. Then I consider bit rates from `ffprobe`.

For testing, I located two h264 files with same dimensions (1280, 720), bit depth (8), and similar file size, frame rate, duration, amount of motion, color content.  To my eye, one of the two looks better, distinctly sharper; that file is *smaller* and has a *lower video bit rate* (20-40%), even when normalized for its slightly lower frame rate and duration.

From an info theory perspective, doesn't seem possible. I've learned codecs can provide "quality" optimizations during compression - way past my understanding - but I can't find, looking at the video stream data, indicators of any that would impact quality/sharpness. Nothing in per-frame and per-packet data from `ffprobe` stands out.

Are there any tell-tale signs I should look for? Is this a fool's errand?

---

Here's my swift hack to run ffprobe inside a macOS application (written with XC 13 on 11.6). If you know how to run a Process() that lives in /usr/bin/..., please post - I don't get the entitlements thing.  (Aliases/links to home directory don't work.)

```swift
// takes a local fileURL and determines video properties using ffprobe
func runFFProbe(targetURL:URL){
    
    func buildArguments(url:URL) -> [String] {
        // for ffprobe introduction,see: https://ottverse.com/ffprobe-comprehensive-tutorial-with-examples/
        // and for complete info: https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html
    
        var arguments:[String] = []
        // note: don't interpolate URL paths - may have spaces in them
        let argString = "-v error -hide_banner -of default=noprint_wrappers=0 -print_format flat -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,bit_rate,codec_name,codec_long_name,profile,codec_tag_string,time_base,avg_frame_rate,r_frame_rate,duration_ts,bits_per_raw_sample,nb_frames "
        let _ = argString.split(separator: " ").map{arguments.append(String($0))}
        // let _ suppresses compiler warning about unused result of map call
        arguments.append(url.path)  // spaces in URL path seem to be okay here
        return arguments
    }
    
    let task = Process()
    // task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/local/bin/ffprobe")
    // reports "doesn't exist", but really access is blocked by macOS :(
    
    // statically-linked ffprobe is added to the app bundle
    // downloadable here - https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/#sExtLib-ffprobe
    task.executableURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ffprobe", withExtension: nil)
    task.arguments = buildArguments(url: targetURL)
    
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe                  // ffprobe writes console thru standardOutput
                                                // (ffmpeg uses standardError)
    let fh = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    
    var cumulativeResults = ""                  // adds the result from each buffer dump
    
    fh.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()       // setup handle for listening
    
    // object must be specified when running multiple simultaneous calls
    // otherwise every instance receives messages from all other filehandles too
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .NSFileHandleDataAvailable, object: fh, queue: nil) {notif in
        
        let closureFileHandle:FileHandle = notif.object as! FileHandle
        // Get the data from the FileHandle
        let data:Data = closureFileHandle.availableData
        // print("received bytes: \(data.count)\n")     // debugging
        
        if data.count > 0 {
            // re-arm fh for any addition data
            fh.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
            // append new data to the accumulator
            let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
            cumulativeResults += str
            // optionally insert code here for intermediate reporting/parsing
            // self.printToTextView(string: str)
        }
    }
    
    task.terminationHandler = {task -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            // run the whole termination on the main queue
            
            if task.terminationReason==Process.TerminationReason.exit {
                // roll your own reporting method
                self.printToTextView(string: targetURL.lastPathComponent)
                self.printToTextView(string: targetURL.fileSizeString) //custom URL extension
                self.printToTextView(string: cumulativeResults)
                let str = "\nSuccess!\n"
                self.printToTextView(string: str)
            } else {
                print("Task did not terminate properly")
                // post an error in UI too
                return
            }
            // successful conversion if this point is reached
        })  // end dispatchqueue
    }       // end termination handler
    
    do { try
        task.run()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        // post in UI too
        return
    }
}   // end runFFProbe()
```

Comment: For quality assessment you should be looking at **pixels**. It helps if you have an example "high quality" reference to test other inputs against. Since your input is a random catalogue, you'll just have to do some tests that help your code decide what is high quality or not. Tests include: [Detect Image Quality using Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52741728/2057709) but you can try other things like Levels Adjustment (as it "white washes" the image, does the lower quality image's pixels degrade into blocks/pixelation more than a (same size) higher quality image using the same levels?

Comment: Before writing any code, you need to use an image editor (like Photoshop or GIMP) to test the effects of RGB adjustments (levels, histogram, posterize filter, etc). Also test blend modes like what happens when you greyscale your input and then blend it with a layer of 50% grey? Which blend modes shows more pixels if image is of higher quality? Test, test and test...

Comment: Thanks @VC.One for thoughtful comments. You're right that adjusting various levels can improve appearance, mask compression artifacts, etc. But there are limits. My question is really about how to infer from the file itself (at least qualitatively) compression settings beyond bitrate that might affect spatial resolution (4:x:x, GOP, etc), and in a practical time. No doubt, testing is important.

Comment: Q2, that is.  WRT Q1, I can't even get bitrate from Apple API.

Comment: I use Windows so I cannot say anything about Apple API. Try **MediaInfo** (open 2 copies) to compare 2 files. If your videos are H264 codec, you have MP4 files (as container)? From MP4 bytes you could check **encoder profile** (which is Baseline, Main and High. Main and High can look equal but both will have a better picture quality than Baseline), so I guess you could drop all Baseline videos as low quality. Baseline could still look crisp if the video is for example about technical diagrams (or basic outline illustrations, just not full color paintings). Also in MP4 bytes is the **bitrate**.

Comment: Great tip!  I'll look into it. For those interested, **MediaInfo** source code is [here](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfo) and pre-built executables for many platforms [here](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)